# How to use a previous raw select calculation for next select raw calculation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
query() ->select([
            'order_items.id',
            DB::raw("(order_qty * mp_price) as grossamount"),
            'order_items.discount_amount',
            DB::raw("(grossamount - discount_amount) as netamount"),
        ])
```

I am using Laravel Spatie Query Builder, but it should work as eloquent. How so I can use grossamount in my next raw statement, as seen above. The above does not work. I want to use the grossamount for netamount. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't chain that in a select statement. You'll need to duplicate the calculation of gross amount for the netamount `((order_qty * mp_price) - discount_amount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use :

```php
query() ->select([
            'order_items.id',
            DB::raw("(order_qty * mp_price) as grossamount"),
            'order_items.discount_amount',
            DB::raw("((order_qty * mp_price) - discount_amount) as netamount"),
        ])
```